# How to overload method running with other data type of parameters?

Tags: java, overloading

I have a short program to test overload method in java.
This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // Case 1
    f2(5);
    // Case 2
    char x = 'a';
    f2(x);
    // Case 3
    byte y = 0;
    f2(y);
    // Case 4
    float z = 0;
    f2(z);
}
```

And there are my methods :

```
public static void prt(String s) {
    System.err.println(s);
}

public static void f2(short x) {
    prt("f3(short)");
}

public static void f2(int x) {
    prt("f3(int)");
}

public static void f2(long x) {
    prt("f5(long)");
}

public static void f2(float x) {
    prt("f5(float)");
}
```

and this is result:

```
f3(int)
f3(int)
f3(short)
f5(float)
```

I can't understand how does it running with case 2 and 3. Any explain for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method invocation in case of overloaded methods will invoke the most specific method based on the type parameters, and the actual type you pass.

Method invocation conversion follows the following path:

- *Identity Conversion:* First the exact matching method will be searched. If found, it will be invoked. Conversion from a type to the same type.
- *Widening Primitive Conversion:* If there is no exact matching method, the method is chosen based on the widening conversion from actual argument to format type parameter.

some more are there, not applicable here though. See [JLS 5.3 for Method Invocation Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3).

So, for `f2(x);` as there is no exact match for `char` type, so the method `f2(int)` is invoked, as the most specific type to which `char` can be converted by widening conversion is `int`. **No, `char` to `short` is not a widening conversion.**

Similary, for `f2(y)`, there is no exact match for `byte` type, so the method `f2(short)` is invoked, as `short` is the most specific type that `byte` can be widened to.

See [JLS 5.1.2 for Widening Primitive conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`